# How to know how to contact YouTube channel moderators?

Tags: youtube

[One of the videos from the University of Florida](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_otSO1Ab9w) had some links at the end of the video. Since, I could not click on the screen, I decided to type each link in the comments. But, later on my comments disappeared. So, I have once again posted a single comment on the video saying "I'm writing the above links here so that we can click them. Please do not remove this comment.", followed by the above links. So, I need to ask the YouTube channel moderators why my previous comments were removed. So, how can I contact YouTube channel moderators?

Comment: The question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site as it's very likely that only the corresponding community moderator will be able to do it.

Comment: Look at channel information to see if they have posted how to do that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the question a good fit for this site. You could change the question to ask that keeping the actual content as context.

Comment: But then whom do I ask a question about YouTube comments and where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123395/discussion-between-ruben-and-arunabh-bhattacharya).

Comment: Hi. I think that the best to as ask to help regarding another post rather than postint a comment on an unrelated to post is to post a question on [meta] or a  message in the [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video description doesn't include community rules / contact details, check out the YouTube user / channel **About**

1. Click in the YouTube video owner / channel

[image: owner/channel located under number of views]

2. Click on the **About** tab

[image: about tab is located next to the discussion tab]

3. Check out the information there:

[image: there are sections for details and links for the channel]

In this specific case, the about page only include an email and a link. YouTube owners / channels administrators can moderate the comments. It's up to them which comments will be kept / deleted and as well as if to offer contact options or not  and if they offer them if they will reply and when.

Related help article:

- [Post & interact with comment](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6000964?hl=en)